# How to link to controller with parameters by Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have following route in phoenix.

```
page_path  GET /next/:id   SampleServerWeb.SampleController :next
```

I would like to send parameter id from previous page.
I have no idea of how to write link helper tag.

I tried following, however it dose not work.

```
    <%= link "NEXT", to: page_path(@conn, :next, id: 40) %>
```

Please give me an advice.
Thanks.

Comment: It is just named `create`. My question is how to link to next page. sorry.

Comment: `page_path(@conn, :next, "40")`.

Comment: it cause error `undefined function page_path/3`

Comment: It does not https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html?#module-helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally It worked!!

```
<%= link "NEXT", to: Routes.page_path(@conn, :next, id: 40) %>
```

I should have put `Routes`.

Answer (score 3):

### Router Paths

Phoenix generates a path helper module for every `Phoenix.Router`.

The paths can be generated with [Router Helpers](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#path-helpers).

### Helper Availability in Views

If you're using `mix phx.new` to create a project, `YourApp.Router.Helpers` will be imported as `Routes` into all of your views. (https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/2c91dc9/installer/templates/phx_single/lib/app_name_web.ex#L88)

### Available Path / URL Functions

The command `mix phx.routes` shows all currently available routes for your router.

To find out the parameters needed to create a path / url, the details can be shown in `iex`.

```sh
$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:6:6] [ds:6:6:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.10.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> h YourApp.Router.example_path
                 def example_path(conn_or_endpoint, action)                 


             def example_path(conn_or_endpoint, action, params)             


           def example_path(conn_or_endpoint, action, id, params)           

iex(2)>
```

### TODO in your case

```
<%= link "NEXT", to: Routes.page_path(@conn, :next, id: 40) %> or
<%= link "NEXT", to: Routes.page_path(@conn, :next, 40) %>
```